# flipping normals in unity can't see walls from outside

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm using Unity to create a map for Level design and when I used flipping normals I can't see the walls from the outside anymore and when I go inside I see the walls. what can I do to fix this without having to start from scratch?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Probuilder? If you are there is a way to flip the normals from there. This link here shows how to use the flip normals tool. https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.probuilder@4.0/manual/Object_FlipNormals.html

Comment: I used the option yes from Probuilder I used it on my walls but now I can't see the walls from the outside when I'm walking with my character. so what do I do to reverse or correct these walls without having to start from scratch?

Comment: You can't have both faces of the wall showing inside of unity, so you need two walls, one pointing in and the other out.